# What is the difference between these two icons in RTC source control

Tags: rtc

In rtc source control beneath 'My Team Areas' :

[image]

I have differing icons for teams. There does not seem to be any difference between the teams, they both belong to the same project area.

What is difference between these two icons :

[image]

and :

[image]

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one represents a team area with a **customized** process.

The second one is for a team area using an **inherited** process.

On the overview tab, on the top right corner, you can click on "customize process" to transform the type of team area.